# Response 413 - Python requests trying POST .png file

Tags: python, post, python-requests, http-status-code-413

I'm using python requests to do a simple post and I need to send a .png image.

```
...
headers ={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 , ...}
url = "http://example_url/xxx"
files = {'image': open('a.png', 'rb')}
    response = requests.post(url,headers=headers,files=files,)
    print (response.status_code)
    return response.text
```

Canno't figure out why I received back a 413 response code from server.

Thank You

Comment: Solved with adding a specific 'Content-type':'image/png' in header.

Answer (score 1):

413 is a Payload Too Large. This is a configure from the server. Check this URL https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-nginx-413-request-entity-too-large/

Good Luck!

Comment: Solved with adding a specific 'Content-type':'image/png' in header.